# Long term effects of an allergy pill? Loratadine

Tags: medications, allergy, antihistamines

Are there any studies/effects of long term use of an allergy pill? I use Loratadine to help control my environmental allergies but I'm concerned about it being an every-day thing. Am I facing any risks by taking an allergy pill every day?

Answer (score 3):

The most common side effect of loratadine is headache which has been reported in up to 12 percent of users. Other common side effects include drowsiness occurring in 8 percent of users, fatigue in 4 percent and dry mouth in three percent. Drinking plenty of water while your dose is in effect can help alleviate these symptoms. Some who use loratadine regularly report that these side effects get better with time. If your side effects appear to be severe, talk to your doctor or pharmacist about whether or not there is a better allergy medication for you.

Common Side Effects of Loratadine

- Sleepiness
- Tiredness
- Stomach pain
- Headache Dry eyes
- dry mouth,dry throat
- Diarrhea
- An opposite reaction in which you feel excited, jittery, or nervous, known as paradoxical CNS stimulation instead of drowsy or sleepy

Severe Side Effects of Loratadine :

- Liver damage or inflammation
- Tightness in the chest or breathing tube
- Passing out or fainting
- Seizures
- Low platelet count (thrombocytopenia)

Reference :

http://www.everydayhealth.com/drugs/loratadine

http://www.md-health.com/Loratadine.html